# Как вывести информацию о свободном пространстве на дисках при помощи php?

Tags: функции, php

Как вывести информацию о свободном пространстве на дисках при помощи php?
Что-то гугл не помог.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.disk-free-space.php

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df

Comment: я не уточнил, а если мне нужно знать свободное место не на веб сервере, а на стороннем?

Comment: @intertex, если сторонний сервер или компьютер сам этой информации каким-нибудь способом не предоставит или у вас нет каких-нибудь средств для управления им, то получить ее в обход вы никак не сможете.

Comment: @Alex Krass, это я понимаю, я бы не задал данный вопрос, если бы у меня не было полного доступа к данному серверу. 
Интересует конкретика, как это можно реализовать. Расскажите, как не в обход всего получить данные?

Comment: Какая операционная система стоит на стороннем сервере? Linux?

А так много вариантов:

- Через [FTP](http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=ftp) функцией [disk_free_space](http://www.php.su/functions/?disk-free-space)
- Выполнить команду получения свободного места через [SHH](http://www.php.su/ssh2_exec)
- Запустить скрипт на сервере через cURL и получить результат
- Для Windows можно обратиться к [win32api](http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=w32api), возможно есть более простые варианты.

Comment: @Alex Krass, спасибо за ответ. ОС WinServer 2008, на нем крутится СУБД MSSQL.

Comment: @Alex Krass, а сам вебсервер на linux-e

Comment: Как вариант, который знаком мне: я бы запустил IIS на WinServer и настроил его на работу с PHP. А дальше на WinServer кладем файлик, отдающий информацию о свободном пространстве диска, а на сервере Linux через cURL принимаем его.

---------

Есть еще такой вариант на просторе интернетов [Script to Get Available and Free Disk Space for SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2444/script-to-get-available-and-free-disk-space-for-sql-server/).

---------

Может кто-то еще посоветует более практичные варианты...